# how to iterate 3 arrays at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have 3 arrays containing different information. 1 array contains a bunch of id's, the second array contains a bunch of dates and the third contains a bunch of names.

I know this is a simple question but I cannot remember how to do it so I apologize for the stupidity.

The 3 arrays look like this:

```
string[] eventIDs = EventID.Split(',');
        string[] eventDates = eventCopyDate.Split(',');
        string[] invNames = investigatorNames.Split(',');
```

the values look like "john Doe,Mark Doe, Tim Doe" hence why the .Split
I've tried a nested for loop here but no success.

```
foreach (var id in eventIDs)
        {
            foreach (var date in eventDates)
            {
                foreach (var name in invNames)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters["@EventID"].Value = int.Parse(id);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorName"].Value = name;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CopyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                    cmd.Parameters["@CopyDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

                }//end name foreach

            }//end date foreach
        }//end id foreach
```

I know that this will just iterate them through an entire array first before going back to the second nested array. I am trying to iterate to the first value in the array, assign them to the variables then go through the second iteration.

So that arrayNames:"john Doe, Mark Doe" arrayDates"12/12/12, 10/12/12" and arrayID:"234,235,236" would be used like:

```
"john Doe" "12/12/12" "234"
"Mark Doe" "10/12/12" "235"
```

Comment: After you split the three arrays, are the elements always aligned? i.e. `eventIDs[0]` is associated with `eventDates[0]` & `investigatorNames[0]` (then so on through the elements)?

Comment: yes, they get stored accordingly then I split them accordingly

Comment: The real solution to this problem is don't use three arrays but a array of custom class that contains the data.  What makes you think the code you posted isn't the solution ( its not ) but you don't explain what results you are getting which tells me you have not debugged the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound is right, I'd look in to using either a class or struct and store the values that way. Always relying on a CSV format begs for failure (what if the name is `Doe, John`? Then you're columns unalign on a split).

Comment: @Ramhound: he does say "I know that this will just iterate them through an entire array first before going back to the second nested array. I am trying to iterate to the first value in the array, assign them to the variables then go through the second iteration." which says that he knows its not the solution and why not. I agree with custom classes though. :)

Comment: the data gets passed from client side to server side in order

Comment: Thank you Chris, I have gone into the debugger hence why I know it will just iterate the deepest nested array first till it has been iterated completely then move back up a loop. I will look into the struct thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `foreach`, just use a normal `for` loop and use your index to reference your arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < eventIDs.Length; i++)
{
    string eventID = eventIDs[i];
    string eventDate = eventDates[i];
    string invName = invNames[i];
}
```

This assumes that the three arrays are all equal length. If this is not the case then it is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `for` loop with a unique index, assuming the 3 three arrays have the same size.

```
string[] eventIDs = EventID.Split(',');
string[] eventDates = eventCopyDate.Split(',');
string[] invNames = investigatorNames.Split(',');

for(int i=0; i<eventIDs.Length;i++) {
    var id = eventIDs[i];
    var date = eventDates[i];
    var name = invNames[i];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@EventID"].Value = int.Parse(id);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorName"].Value = name;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CopyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@CopyDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
}
```

If you actually wants a foreach, you could write this, but it's less readable in my sense :

```
var assembled = Enumerable.Range(0, eventIDs.Length).Select(i=> new { id=eventIDs[i], name=invName[i], date=eventDates[i] } );

foreach(var value in assembled){

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@EventID"].Value = int.Parse(value.id);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorName"].Value = value.name;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CopyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@CopyDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(value.date);

}
```

But I would prefer the first solution.

Comment: You shouldn't use a language construct because you feel like it but because it is the right one. Foreach just doesn't work as you've said. The only way to get it to do so would be to have a counter incremented in your foreach loop that you then use to access the second and third arrays but this would be more messy than a standard for loop.

Comment: a little check `var minLength = Math.Min(eventIds.Length, Math.Min(eventDates.Length, invNames.Length));` `for(var i = 0; i < minLength;i++)` wouldn't be that expensive, no ?

Comment: I am getting the information from client side in a specific order so the data is stored accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. However I am not very good at Enumerable. I'd use this but I don't understand it well enough in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Enumerable.Range simply projects a sequence of integer, form 0 to eventIds.Length.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for-loop to iterate N times where N is the length of all three arrays (they have to be the same size). Use the loop variable to index into all of them.

Alternatively, you can Zip the arrays but that would be quite complex and awkward compared to a simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
foreach(var data in eventIDs.Zip(eventDates,
                                 (x, y) => new { EventID = x, EventDate = y })
                            .Zip(invNames,
                                 (x, y) => new { EventID = x.EventID,
                                                 EventDate = x.EventDate,
                                                 InvName = y }))
{

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@EventID"].Value = int.Parse(data.EventID);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorName"].Value = data.InvName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CopyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@CopyDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(data.EventDate);

}
```

This looks quite a bit more complex but it has the advantage that it will work without problems even when the arrays aren't of the same length.
To be honest, I don't think I would prefer this approach over a more simple for loop.

Comment: +1, I like seeing a new approach. May be a little unnecessary in terms of overhead, but still cool nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate by index (if you are sure that they are all of the same size):

```
for(int i = 0; i < eventIDs.Length; i++)
{
    var id = eventIDs[i];
    var date = eventDates[i];
    var name = invNames[i];
}
```